# How to make an intersection of two arrays using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

In postgresql i can do this

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE string_to_array(lower(title), ' ') && array['my']
```

but i do not know and can't find how to do this using sqlalchemy orm. I have async connection to a database

```
engine = create_async_engine(config.ASYNC_SQLALCHEMY_URL, echo=True)


async_session = async_sessionmaker(
    engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
)


async def get_async_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
        await session.commit()
```

Guys do you know?

I found in the sqlalchemy documentation and in the Internet

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling the `&&` operation on the output of `string_to_array`, and passing the second array as the argument to this call, like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

q = sa.select(tbl.c.col).where(
    sa.func.string_to_array(sa.func.lower(tbl.c.col), ' ').op('&&')(['my'])
)
```

This example uses a synchronous connection, but the `select` query itself is exactly the same for synchronous or asynchronous connections.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

strings = [
    'In my house',
    'My shoes',
    'Amy Parker',
    'Captain Obvious',
]

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=False)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    for string in strings:
        res = conn.execute(
            sa.select(sa.literal(string)).where(
                sa.func.string_to_array(
                    sa.func.lower(sa.literal(string)), ' '
                ).op('&&')(['my'])
            )
        )
        print(res.fetchone())
```

Output

```
('In my house',)
('My shoes',)
None
None
```